# EditText not receiving focus with sliding drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, slidingdrawer

I tried everything but could not get the editText focused when application starts. Even when I click on it, it does not receive the focus. What looks strange is that it works on the tablet(Galaxy Tab 3 10.1) and not working on my phone (Samsung ACE3).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF666666" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/negaive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/positive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/note_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.muapp.ui.view.LinedEditText
            android:id="@+id/noteText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FF4d4d4d" >
        <requestFocus />

        </com.muapp.ui.view.LinedEditText>

        <com.vis.kotob.ui.view.SemiClosedSlidingDrawer
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.vis.kotob"
            android:id="@+id/mySlidingDrawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            custom:allowSingleTap="true"
            custom:content="@+id/quote"
            custom:handle="@+id/handle"
            custom:orientation="vertical"
            custom:semiClosedContentSize="40dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_note_handle" />

            <com.muapp.ui.view.PreviewTextView
                android:id="@+id/quote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFF2F2F2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FF6b6b6b" />
        </com.muapp.ui.view.SemiClosedSlidingDrawer>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#FFf2f2f2"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_note_delete"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_note_share"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please remove  from your xml code and trye to use bellow code i hope resolve your problem....

```
 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: They keyboard is now shown yes but the focus problem is still there. I mean if for example you clicked the back key, the keyboard disappears and you can not get it back again even if you clicked on the edittext.